# Git bundled into Cocoa app cannot find helpers in bundle

Tags: macos, git, cocoa, nstask

## Context:

I have a Mac app. I want to include Git in this app because some functions of my app use Git and I don't want the user to have to install it on his machine.

I have downloaded Git from source. I edited the Makefile to declare these two lines:

```
NO_GETTEXT="yesPlease"
CURLDIR=/usr/local
```

The first line tells the build process to skip localizing and just use English.
The second line declares the path to where `libcurl` is installed. I downloaded `libcurl_devel` and built it from source. This is required to enable Git to pull/push from `http` and `https` repos.

Git builds successfully. I then copy all of the resulting files into my app's bundle. I'm using NSTask to run Git and attempt to pull an `https://`-based repo.

## The Problem:

The error I get is:

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

I googled this, and everyone said that as long as I had `libcurl` installed when I built Git, Git would work with HTTP and HTTPS addresses. And, in fact, if I run the installed Git from the command line, it does!

## What I Need:

So, I must be missing a path setting or an environment variable or SOMETHING that tells Git where to find those remote helpers. They ARE in my app bundle; the screenshot below shows them:

[image]

So: what the hell do I need to set in order to resolve this problem when I run Git from within my application bundle?

Comment: I'm just stabbing in the dark here, but shouldn't you point the bundled Git at a libcurl that's also bundled rather than locally installed?

Comment: From what I read, libcurl was only needed while building Git. I don't think it needs to be bundled with the app. And the error seems to imply that Git can't locate the "git-remote-https" helper in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbelievable. I've been trying to fix this for 8+ hours and five minutes after I finally break down and post this question, I figure it out:

Git has an option called `--exec-path`. I had been passing this argument to the NSTask like this (Where APP BUNDLE is replaced by the path to the application bundle on the user's machine):

`--exec-path=[APP BUNDLE]/git/bin`

Since `bin` was the folder where the Git binary was located, I figured that was the appropriate path. However, if I do this:

`--exec-path=[APP BUNDLE]/git/libexec/git-core`

It works.

Comment: You should accept your own answer -- make it green!

Comment: Thanks! Had forgotten about this.